# Boot to blank terminal after editing xorg.conf

Tags: xorg, display, display-resolution

After adding this to `xorg.conf` and restarting

```
Subsection "Display" 
     Virtual 4096 4096
EndSubsection
```

My computer boots to a text user interface, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, login using the text user interface.

Then, you can either:

- Remove your `xorg.conf` file with `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Or:

- Remove the line from the file by editing it with `nano` -> `sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

I would recommend the second option.

Both will solve your problem and on reboot you'll have your GUI back.